# Remove leading zeros from middle of filename in Bash

Tags: sed, filenames

This is a simple problem that I'm having but I'm not quite good with `sed` so any quick help would be appreciated.

I broke a number of different files up into 100 chunks using `split`. As a result, all of the single-digit chunks have a leading zero (e.g. `BRNSPC_varID_chunk_07.txt`). I want to remove the leading zero after the underscore to make it look like this: `BRNSPC_varID_chunk_7.txt`. I do not want to affect any trailing zeros (i.e. I want `BRNSPC_varID_chunk_70.txt` to remain `BRNSPC_varID_chunk_70.txt`). Can someone help me rename all of these files in a quick way? It's causing an error with my R script that I don't know how to deal with in R.

Also, one of the files is just `BRNSPC_varID_chunk_00.txt`. I want that to just be `BRNSPC_varID_chunk_0.txt`.

thank you

Comment: Try this: `for file in ./*.txt; do first_part="${file%_*}"; f="${file##*_}"; if [[ $f =~ ^0[0-9]+ ]]; then f="${file/0/}"; echo mv -- "$file" "$f"; fi; done`   If you are happy with the result, remove `echo` in front of `mv` command

Comment: why do you want to do this?  the leading zeroes are there so that the split filenames sort correctly....without them, you'll have to manually list each individual file in the correct order whenever you want to use them.   The leading zeroes also ensure that each filename is the same length, so listing them in columns lines up properly.

Comment: What was your `split` command? You may be able to redo the split and have the filenames correct from the start.

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
$ touch BRNSPC_varID_chunk_07.txt BRNSPC_varID_chunk_00.txt BRNSPC_varID_chunk_70.txt
```

then in at least `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`

```
$ for f in ./*chunk_0?.txt; do echo mv "$f" "${f/chunk_0/chunk_}"; done
mv ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_00.txt ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_0.txt
mv ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_07.txt ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_7.txt
```

Remove the `echo` once you are satisfied that it is going to do the right thing.

You can remove the `chunk` prefix if there is no ambiguity (i.e. if the `_0` sequence cannot occur elsewhere in the name).

There are lots of other less portable solutions with `rename`, `mmv` etc. for example using `rename` from `util-linux`:

```
rename.ul -n -v chunk_0 chunk_ ./*chunk_0?.txt
```

(remove the `-n` to actually rename).

Comment: generating all of these `mv` commands and then copy+pasting them destroyed a lot of the filenames. I have a ton of resulting files that look like this `SKINNS_varID_chunk_7.t  ` or like this `ESPMSL_varID_chunk_0`. I guess I should have saved the output to a `.sh` file but it didn't occur to me to do so; I thought command-line would be able to handle it. It's not a problem because I can regenerate these files, however.

Answer (score 1):

Using `rename`:

```
rename 's/(BRNSPC_varID_chunk_)0([0-9])/$1$2/' *.txt
```

`*.txt` will expand to all `.txt` files in the current directory.

rename will look for any file containing `BRNSPC_varID_chunk_0[0-9]` Where the first match group is `BRNSPC_varID_chunk_` and the second match group is the trailing `[0-9]` it will the replace this with just the first and second match group (eliminating the zero in the middle).

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of selecting the correct regex to match the string to replace.

You have tagged the question with sed.

In `sed`, with ERE syntax (to avoid the several `\`):

```
s#(chunk_)0+([0-9]+\.)#\1\2#
```

That will replace the text `chunk_` (and capture it as the first backreference `\1`) followed by any amount (at least one) of (leading) zeros `0+` followed by any amount of numbers (at least one), followed by a dot `\.` and convert what was matched with the backreferences `\1\2` (removing the several leading zeros).

With older, but more portable, syntax, it is:

```
s#\(chunk_\)0\{1,\}\([0-9]\{1,\}\.\)#\1\2#
```

That will convert:

```
for file in ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk*.txt; do
    filenew=$(echo "$file" | sed -E 's#(chunk_)0+([0-9]+\.)#\1\2#')
    echo mv -n "$file" "$filenew"
done
```

That, using sed, only makes sense on shells that do not have regex support.

In bash, you can do:

```
regex='(.*chunk_)0+([0-9]+\..*)'

for file in ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk*.txt; do
    if [[ $file =~ $regex ]]; then
        filenew=$(IFS=;printf '%s' "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}") 
        echo mv -n "$file" "$filenew"
    fi
done
```

That will print this type of list:

```
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_000000.txt ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_0.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_0000.txt   ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_0.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_00011.txt  ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_11.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_000.txt    ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_0.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_00.txt     ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_0.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_010.txt    ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_10.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_011.txt    ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_11.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_012.txt    ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_12.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_013.txt    ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_13.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_014.txt    ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_14.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_015.txt    ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_15.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_01.txt     ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_1.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_02.txt     ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_2.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_03.txt     ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_3.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_04.txt     ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_4.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_05.txt     ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_5.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_06.txt     ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_6.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_07.txt     ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_7.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_08.txt     ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_8.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_09.txt     ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_9.txt
mv -n ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_0.txt      ./BRNSPC_varID_chunk_0.txt
```

Note that it deals correctly with **several** zeros.

Comment: I'm trying to make your last recommendation work, as I had to redo my `split` command and now my files are numbered from `001` to `100`, and for some reason it does not work. I get no output.
`regex='(.*chunk_)0+([0-9]+\..*)'

for file in ./*_varID_chunk*.txt; do
    if [[ $file =~ $regex ]]; then
        filenew=$(IFS=;printf '%s' "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}") 
        echo mv -n "$file" "$filenew"
    fi
done
`

Comment: Are you using a recent bash? Have you written the code to an script? or Are you typing the commands on the command line?

Comment: If copying the script to the command line you need some aditional `;`.